# mysql CREATE TABLE STRING_TO_DATE unify two date formats

Tags: mysql, datetime, create-table, string-to-datetime

I'm trying to create a new table from my query-results with the following code while having two different date formats (formatted as **text** in the tweet table) in the same column:

```
Create Table tweets_adj
select
t.fullname as company_name,
t.`user` as twitter_user_name,
t.id as tweet_id,
cast(t.likes as unsigned int) as likes,
cast(t.replies as unsigned int) as replies,
cast(t.retweets as unsigned int) as retweets,

case 
    when right(t.`text`,1)="'" and left(t.text, 2) = "b'" then left(replace(t.`text`, "b'", ""), length(replace(t.`text`, "b'", ""))-1)
    when right(t.`text`,1)='"' and left(t.text, 2) = 'b"' then left(replace(t.`text`, 'b"', ''), length(replace(t.`text`, 'b"', ''))-1)    
     else t.`text` end as content,

case 
    when STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp, '%Y.%m.%d %H:%i:%s') is null
        then STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i') 
        else STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') 
end as timestamp,
t.url,
t.hashtags
from tweets t
limit 1000;
```

I have to sorts of timestamps in the column timestamp: 
20.08.2014 20:17
2014-03-10 02:19:02

I want to unify them to one date format (none specific format preferred) and save them in the right format as a date and then export the whole select into a new query.

Unfortunately I get an error:

> Incorrect datetime value: '20.08.2014 20:17:00'

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311760/cant-create-mysql-table-due-to-incorrect-datetime-value-for-function-str) but I'm too much of a beginner to understand that solution.

[table tweets looks like this - all columns are formated as text e.g.   `fullname` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', (...) `timestamp` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', (...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UASwS.jpg)

Any help is so much appreciated - Thanks!!

Comment: if your tweets.timestamp column is a Timestamp Type, try without using the STR_TO_DATE function and see what you have. The structure of tweets table would help here

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Trying without STR_TO_DATE yields in error 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)' or 'SQL syntax error'. All columns have a simple text structure: CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
 `fullname` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', (...)

Comment: I also edited the question.

Comment: then STR_TO_DATE(t.timestamp, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')  %s is missing from this line. Please update and check.

Comment: Thanks @Jyotimishra for your help! Valid point, the %s is missing but I still get an incorrect datetime value...

Comment: what is your timestamp value?

Comment: not too sure what you mean.. **timestamp from table tweets:** 20.08.2014 20:17 (create table statement (...) `timestamp` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', (...) **timestamp from new table:** 2014-08-20 20:17:00  >>> so the select part of the code itself works just fine, only when I add `Create table tweets_adj` I get the mistake.

Comment: are you still getting same error ?

Comment: @Jyotimishra yes: I updated my question with the current code. I get the above mentioned results but as soon as I add `create table` I get the incorrect date time value error.

Comment: Does your database contains any value "20.08.2014 20:17" ?

Comment: yes (you can see the entry in the picture above)

Comment: Can you please change your value from  20.08.2014 20:17 to 20.08.2014 20:17:00 to check. I think it should work

Comment: I altered the data in the tweet database. I also altered it to 20-08-2014 (...); still getting the same problem. so... I need to make sure that all dates have the same fomat and then create a table out of the adjustet data. Maybe there is another, smarter way?